# How to schedule my Quartz which run after every 10 minute except Saturday & Sunday

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am not being able to customize my quartz schedular which will run after every 10 minute except Saturday & Sunday.

please tell me how could i customize my schedular which will fire after every 10 minute every day except saturday and Sunday?

```
public partial class QuartzTest : Form , IJob
    {
        IScheduler sched = null;

        public QuartzTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("job start");
        }

        private void QuartzTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // construct a scheduler factory
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

            // get a scheduler
            sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
            sched.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<QuartzTest>()
                .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
               .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                 (s =>
                    s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                   .OnEveryDay()
                   .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(19, 07))
                 )
               .Build();

            sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }

        private void QuartzTest_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            sched.Shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Please tell me how to mention trigger should fire after every 10 minute and also ignore Saturday & Sunday. please share example which help me to reach my goal. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use a cron trigger. Something like this:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
    .WithCronSchedule("* 0/5 * ? * MON-FRI")
    .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

---

Find more about the cron trigger, [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html). You could also find this [tool](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=*%200%2F5%20*%20%3F%20*%20MON-FRI&locale=en) quite helpful.

Comment: please explain what is the meaning of this expression `* 0/5 * ? * MON-FRI` what is 0/5 specially ?